# C# Console application grid calculation

Tags: c#, console-application

I am trying to write a console application in C# that counts the number of unique blocks a robot is moving through in a grid on a floor. The input takes instructions for movement using the four compass points such as : N ,E ,S W.

The application processes the amount of blocks the robot travels through once, if the X co-ordinate and Y co-ordinate of the robot's path cross at any time, that block is counted once and not twice. For instance if the robot travels N4, 2E , 2S and 4W, there will be an intersection of x and y on the 2nd block the robot travelled at the beginning of it's movement.

This is what I have so far:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        //List<string> movements = new List<string>();

        int x1 = 0;
        int y1 = 0;

        int x2 = 0;
        int y2 = 0;

        int x3 = 0;
        int y3 = 0;

        int x4 = 0;
        int y4 = 0;



        int N, S, E, W, Total;
        string coordinate1, coordinate2, coordinate3, coordinate4;


        Console.Write("Enter North : ");
        N = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        if(N != 0)
        {
            x1 += 0;
            y1 += N;

        }
        coordinate1 = "(" + x1 + "," + y1 + ")";








        Console.Write("Enter East: ");
        E = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        if (E != 0)
        {
            y3 += 0;
            x3 += E;

        }
        coordinate3 = "(" + x3 + "," + y3 + ")";



        Console.Write("Enter South: ");
        S = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        if (S != 0)
        {
            x2 += 0;
            y2 -= S;

        }

        coordinate2 = "(" + x2 + "," + y2 + ")";


        Console.Write("Enter West: ");
        W = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        if (W != 0)
        {
            y4 += 0;
            x4 -= W;

        }
        coordinate4 = "(" + x4 + "," + y4 + ")";




        if (coordinate1 == coordinate2|| coordinate1== coordinate3 || coordinate1 == coordinate4 || coordinate2 == coordinate3 || coordinate2 == coordinate4 || coordinate3 ==coordinate4 )
        {
            Total = (N + S + E + W) - 1 ;
            Console.WriteLine("The total Blocks travelled are " + Total);
        }

        else
        {
            Total = N + S + E + W;
            Console.WriteLine("The total Blocks travelled are " + Total);
        }



    }
```

Comment: the best way to approach this is to ask yr teacher or TA. Nobody here will write code from scratch for you. Not knowing how much you know its hard to offer pointers

Comment: @pm100 I've update the question with some of the code I'v completed, I was able to do a basic calculation of the inputs, i'm not sure how to go forward with how to determine if a block has been passed before.

Comment: Is the input ("the sequence of steps the robot will take") an arbitrary list of movements, e.g. `N7 E2 S4 E9 N6 W14` or, as your code indicates, only one offset in each of four directions?

Comment: @HABO It is actually meant to be an arbitrary list like you have stated, but I felt it was simpler for me to understand the way I did it, entering one at a time.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with simple math. And this is simple way if you want more complex i can write it too.

```
    int N,S,E,W,Total;
    Console.Write("Enter North : ");
    N=int.Parse(Console.Readline());

    Console.Write("Enter South: ");
    S=int.Parse(Console.Readline());

    Console.Write("Enter East: ");

    E=int.Parse(Console.Readline());

    Console.Write("Enter West: ");
    W=int.Parse(Console.Readline());

    if(N > S)
       Total = N-S;
    else
       Total = S-N;

    if(E > W)
       Total += (E-W)
    else
       Total += (W-E)

    Console.Write("Final Total Step are : "+Total);
```

Comment: [`Math.Abs()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.abs?view=netframework-4.7.1) would simplify things.

Comment: but Math.Abs() can take just 1 parameter and this method can't does compare with multiple values

Comment: @KadirKalkan thank you for your help sir, unfortunately this does not work. I for instance the robot moves 4 blocks North, 2 Blocks East, 2 Blocks South and 4 Blocks West, the Robot would have moved a total of 12 blocks, but it would have passed a block it had already moved through( X would intersect with Y) and therefore the number of unique blocks would be 11

Comment: I was thinking of `Total = Abs( N - S ) + Abs( E - W );`, a much shorter implementation of the wrong arithmetic.

Comment: @HABO I have updated my question to make it a bit easier to interpret. would using this method account for a block that is travelled through 2 times?

Comment: Now can you tell me what will give this code at final as Result
Robot moved +5 step or Robot moved +2stepN and +3StepW

Comment: @ThomasNadhir Where does it keep track of the blocks that have already been traversed? There's your answer.

Comment: i don't understand what he want ? İs he want this scenario must create with code we have to hold every block's data or just think like this and count robot's total + step or count robot's + steps with direction

Comment: Imagine that the robot has an, um, oil retention issue. After the robot finishes wandering around, just count the number of blocks that have oil stains. Some may have large puddles, e.g. if the robot wandered back and forth in front of the Quickie Lube after hours, but each besmirched block is counted only once. At least that's what I _think_ the OP wants.

Comment: @HABO thank you for your input, it has helped with understanding, I will try to store the blocks traveled in a 2d array

Comment: @ThomasNadhir That should work. If you want to try something a little different, keep a sorted list of the blocks traversed. If the robot visits a block already on the list the list doesn't change. At the end, the length of the list is the answer. It has the advantage that you don't need to guess how far the robot might go, i.e. does you array need to be 5 by 5 or 100 by 100? Is the middle of the array `[0,0]` so that the robot can head in any direction?

Comment: @HABO a sorted list may be a better option than an array in the sense that the question states that the size of the grid is unknown and unspecified.

Comment: @ThomasNadhir The question _as posted_ does not mention the size of the grid. I suggested a list rather than array based on the [SWAG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_wild-ass_guess) that the array size would become an issue either due to inputs that cause the robot to wander off the grid or simply because the space required will tend to go up in a square, rather than linear, relationship to the distance the robot wanders. A _sorted_ list makes handling repeated visits to the same block easier. A binary tree would be more efficient if it is justified by the path length.

Comment: @HABO I have updated my code that I have so far, I was able to work out some of the coordinates, but the problem is, that the co ordinates are after each input, I need all the coordinates inbetween the coordinates I have worked out because an intersection may occur on any coordinate, please can you advise me on how to move forward or how to refactor my code.

Comment: @ThomasNadhir I'd start with something like: 1. Empty list, position `0, 0`, moves = 0. 2. Enter direction (N,S,E,W, or Q to quit), enter distance. 3. For count = 1 to distance: moves++, calculate new position, add position to list if not present. 4 Print total moves counter and list length as unique blocks visited. Go back to step 2. Tip: When N xIncrement = 0, yIncrement = 1; when S xIncrement = 0, yIncrement = -1; when E xIncrement = 1, yIncrement = 0; when W ... . Then just use `x += xIncrement; y += yIncrement;` inside the the `for` loop.